# Java Web Start and Main Class

Tags: java, class, web, program-entry-point

I made an application and i would have an auto-update at start. Reading on stackoverflow many people suggest Java web start.
So with Netbeans i enabled web start configuration and soon on. It generated launch.jnpl html , jar file and lib folder.
In the main of program i insert

```
DownloadService2 service = (DownloadService2)
ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.DownloadService2");                        
ResourceSpec spec = new ResourceSpec("http://www.mysite:8080/.*", "1.*", service.JAR);
ResourceSpec results[] = service.getCachedResources(spec);
 results = service.getUpdateAvailableResources(spec);
```

SO i uploaded all files in dist folder to webserver. Now if i start the application with lunch.jnpl it starts without problem. But when i use my jar file i got error : Could not find main class "My class" program exit.

Now if i dont use DownloadService2 it works with Jar File.
So my question is : 
How could i use Java Web start to Update my program?

For example if i release another version and put it codebase url, if i start program with jar file it should downloads new version.

Could someone tell my if i wrong something or misunderstood how Java web start works ?

Edit: i would that programs follows this line : 
1) lunch with jar if it's possibile , Check for update...if it cant becouse offline use the old ones 
2) if online check for update if aviable download update in the folder
3) if update not aviable use older one.
repeat 1 2 3

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a two parter now, isn't it:

First, why do you get an error about your main class? Does your jnlp file have the correct package and name of the main class declared? It should be something like:

```
<application-desc main-class="package1.package2.MyMainClass" />
```

Secondly, how does the update work. Well once someone accesses your jnlp file and starts your jar application from it, that jar is downloaded locally on the client's machine. Then, when he runs it a second time, the jnlp protocol will first check the url to see if the jar has been update. If so, then it gets that new version and that's what the client will run. If it hasn't been updated the previouslly downloaded jar will be run from local machine.

Comment: </resources> <application-desc main-class="mypackage.myclass"> </application-desc> there is class in jpln and how can i do those step write in my edit topic?   Start jar (that doesnt start) check for update if online download new aviable update in folder, or if there arent update  launch it. IF offline use older one in the folder.